# Flush edges when setting NSBackgroundColorAttributeName for attributed string

Tags: ios, nsattributedstring

I have an `NSAttributedString`, part of which is highlighted using the `NSBackgroundColorAttributeName` property.

But this is what the final output looks like
[image]

I want the color to be flush to the sides of the page so there's no white space before when the text starts and after it ends.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like below...

> If that is the only attributed string you'd be using then, you could set background color
>   of the UI Object(UILabel, UIButton...).

But I beleive that you're using more than one attributed strings merged, In that case

> You could prefix and suffix your string with new line character
>   "\n".

DISCLAIMER: 
 **This will comprise a new line at the top and bottom along with your attributed string.**

Comment: Yeah, the string is a part of a bigger string and I need the background color on only a part of the string. And yes, adding line breaks is an option but I was kinda hoping to avoid adding any space more than necessary